# Batch file not executing directly (double click)

Tags: batch-file

Just wrote a simple batch file to kill the given process.

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p ProcName=Enter process name:
taskkill /IM "%ProcName%" /t /f
```

I saved it as `taskkill.bat` . I double clicked this bat file , A command prompt window appeared and asked `Enter process name:` Whatever process name I gave every time it asked the same message and did not execute `taskkill` command at all.

Now in a `cmd`  window I dragged the batch file and as usual it asked `Enter process name:` I gave the process name and it killed the process successfully.

What happened first time ? And why it is executing second time ?

Comment: Did you executed the script with administrator priviliges the second time? `taskkill` requires an administrator rights to be executed - else it will print `access dennied` (you can set a pause at the end of the script to see what happens).To kill process without need of special permissions you can use `tskill`

Comment: Exactly ! But when I dragged the batch file in command prompt, that command prompt was running without admin privilage ? 

Please post it as answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone noticed that the batch file name is the same as the executable.

**taskkill.bat**

That's not going to work...

Comment: I appreciate your answer npocmaka . But this one is the right answer. The file name and command name is same. I changed the file name task_kill.bat and a simple double click is working. No need to start it with Admin privilages.

Answer (score 1):

> Did you executed the script with administrator priviliges the second
>   time? taskkill requires an administrator rights to be executed - else
>   it will print access dennied (you can set a pause at the end of the
>   script to see what happens).To kill process without need of special
>   permissions you can use tskill

---

> Exactly ! But when I dragged the batch file in command prompt, that
>   command prompt was running without admin privilage ?

That's a great trick! - just tested it :-) .May it should be considered as a security hole